# Save video URL to Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiimagepickercontroller

In my app, I utilize the UIImagePickerController to record a video. I then save the video URL from the camera roll into core data, and whenever I want to play it, I pull the URL and do so. However, when the video is deleted from the photos app, it still plays for a couple of days. When it is not deleted from the photos app, it is still deleted after a couple of days. How can I save the video into my app's documents, and save a url to it into core data? Here is what I am using currently (It doesnt work):

Here is the zip file that doesn't work: http://jmp.sh/v/w4gE5SXNiRd0d7tasc3U

Here is the zip file that now works without errors: http://jmp.sh/v/tzyJU3nlc1qOPI9ZzDTF

```
 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
 NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
 // Handle a movie capture
 if (CFStringCompare((__bridge_retained CFStringRef)mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {
 NSString *moviePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path]];
 NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
 NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];

 AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 _managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
 Video *video = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Video" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

 [video setVideoData:videoData];

 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
 int random = arc4random() % 1000;
 //[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/vid1.mp4"]
 NSString *tempPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"vid%d%@%@.mp4", random, self.currentAthlete.first, self.currentAthlete.last]];
 BOOL success = [videoData writeToFile:tempPath atomically:NO];
 if (success == FALSE) {
 NSLog(@"Video was not successfully saved.");
 }
 else{
 [video setVideoURL:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", tempPath]];
 }

 NSError *error = nil;
 if (![_managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
 }

 if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath)) {
 UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath, self,
 @selector(video:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
 }
 }
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
 }
```

Comment: What the problem you are facing with current implementation ?

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre: I don't want to play the video from the photos app, I want to have the videos save in my app so the user cannot delete the videos.

Comment: You are saving video in documents directory, so save that path only in core data. don't save video url which you are getting from camera roll.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre: I tried that but it doesn't work. Ill update my question with that code.

Comment: check my answer, It will resolved your problem,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create path like this:

```
NSString *tempPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/vid%d%@%@.mp4", documentsDirectory, random, self.currentAthlete.first, self.currentAthlete.last];
```

create like this:

```
NSString *tempPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"vid%d%@%@.mp4", random, self.currentAthlete.first, self.currentAthlete.last]];
```

Comment: Is there anything else wrong with my code? There aren't any errors in Xcode but I can't still can't play it.

Comment: First you are saving video data to core data, don't do that. just save path of video in core data. And save that path into core data.

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean? How will I play the video from a URL if the video doesn't exist? Don't I have to use the video data to write it to my documents directory? Can you show me what you mean??

Comment: I given you right way of creating path. based on path write your video data, it will definitely write into your documents directory. And while playing get data from your saved path and play it.

Comment: It doesn't work... I must be doing something wrong, because if I try to play it, it gives me an empty player.

Comment: Make sure that your data is there in documents directory. And you are giving write path only.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42264/discussion-between-josue-espinosa-and-bhumeshwer-katre)

Answer (score 6):

Core Data itself.

Wait, before you claim that you shouldn't store large binary objects into the Core Data Store directly, I agree. You shouldn't.

However, there is an option in Core Data for storing binary data using External Storage if the file is large.

[image]

Now, if the file is large, Core Data will take care of saving the file and storing the URL.

Saves you managing the data files.

Comment: Take in account that if you fetch a `NSSet` of `NSManageObjects` which have `NSData` properties (load from external storage), then it could raise in a memory warning or app crash.

Comment: Not necessarily true, You only use the memory when the objects are faulted in.

Comment: Of course. I mean when showing that data in a collection i.e. `UITableView`, all `NSData` properties are loaded. Additionally if  you are working with images and you need to resize them, then you'll have in memory for each image, the `NSData` property and the `UIImage` resized. Maybe for videos if not the same case.

Comment: There are ways of working around all of these issues.

Comment: I've added a question about this, thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22454280/how-to-free-memory-using-core-data-external-storage

Answer (score 0):

This code writes the NSData object to documents directory(you can prefer another location) with specifying its URL and after that saves the same URL to core data.

(.h)

```
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSData *data;
```

(.m)

```
    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[@"video_" stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d.mp4", 0]]]];

    [self.data writeToFile:databasePath atomically:YES];
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:databasePath];

    if(videoURL)
    {
        //save url to core data 
    }
```

Comment: I think this is a good start but wouldn't this block the thread when saving a very large video file? Maybe wrapping the write to file with a completion handler to ensure that you continue only when the URL is definitely valid. ~ Would improve the answer.